# Reslet Netty Configuration - Thread Pool Sizes

Tags: netty, restlet

I've got Restlet set up and working for my project, without too many problems. I've decided to vend the services over Netty, and I've managed to set that up without too many problems. I'm forcing Restlet's hand to use Netty via the following code:

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers().add(0, new org.restlet.ext.netty.HttpServerHelper(null));
```

This is similarly working well, but I'd like to tweak the number of threads given for the HTTP  processing. Having previously used Jetty, I was using

```
Series<Parameter>   params = restletServer.getContext().getParameters();
params.add("minThreads", ...);
params.add("maxThreads", ...);
```

However, I'm uncertain of how to configure the size of the thread pool in netty.

Could anybody help shine some light on the subject.

Thansk all,

jwa

Answer (score 0):

The Netty connector has been removed in version 2.1. It was only experimental in 2.0.

You should migrate to version 2.1 if possible, or at least use the Simple or Jetty connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Why this connector has been removed? It seems that Netty is one of the fastest frameworks worldwide (http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/28/framework-benchmarks/
)... It could be interesting also to have restlets in this comparison...

regards
Xavier